# Sub headings in tab navigation bar

Tags: editing-menu

I am trying to create a dynamic menu list with the top navigation bar that will have sub headings, if possible.

I want to be able to hover the mouse over Heading 1 which will display a list of links and headings, so that when I now hover over one of the headings in the list a further list of links and headings appear.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google or Bing how you can modify the DynamicChildLimit of your Site Map Provider.

SP OOB navigation is quite limited so you might want to look at custom navication controls. I found security trimming to be the biggest problem with third part solutions because if you are dynamically calculating permissions across a farm it can easily become too much load.
Still, if you need navigation across site collections you really don't have much choice.
Otherwise, I'm planning to use cube4 megamenu in my current project (unless we move to 2013 in the mean time )